# docker-compose + spring boot few application don't connect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I create 2 spring boot application. ConnectToBd and ResourceCalculate

application.properties:

```
nsi.url=http://ip:port/odo/find/root/
bd_connect=http://ip:port/connect-to-bd/getdata?
```

Spring controller:

```
@PropertySource("application.properties")
@RestController
public class ResourceCalculateCntr {

@Value("${nsi.url}")
private String nsi;

@Value("${bd_connect}")
private String connect;

@RequestMapping(value = "getProperties", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String retProps() {
    return nsi + "    " + connect;
}
```

build with gradle

Dockerfile bdconnect and calculate. Example:

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXROSE 8080
ADD resourceCalculate.war resourceCalculate.war
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "resourceCalculate.war"]
```

docker build succesfull

then I use docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  calc:
    image: calculate
    container_name: calc
    ports:
      - "2020:8080"
    enviroment:
      - bd_connect=connect
    depend_on:
      - connect
    links:
      - connect
    networks:
      - calc-net
  connect:
    image: dbconnect
    container_name: connect
    ports:
      - "1010:8080"
    networks:
      - calc_net

networks:
  calc_net:
    driver: bridge
```

do docker-compose up and write: Creating done
Then I enter in container: 'docker-compose exec calc sh' and 'ping connect' all okey
But if I request webservice in browser I see response:

```
http://ip:port/odo/find/root/ connect
```

Why so?